# Opencart theme development from scratch

Tags: php, themes, opencart

I am creating the theme for `Opencart 2.2`.

While creating a `Opencart` theme do I always need to copy the files from the `default` theme? What about I want to create my own layout? Is there any good tutorial are available for creating a opencart theme without using the default theme?

Looking for your reply.

Thanks and Regards,
Chirag

Comment: Yes @Chirag, You need to take copy of default them and then you will create your own theme same as opencart default structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @VipulJethva. Then to create my theme I always need to use default theme?

Comment: Yes @Chirag, You will take copy of default theme and then you will change any of the files to your theme files. **Don't delete folder and files of default theme** If you want to require changes on controller and model files then you will use vqmod or ocmode.

Comment: @VipulJethva Okay thanks. I will dig more into it today.

Comment: To note: You don't have to duplicate all of the core themes files, only the ones that you actually are going to modify. Opencart will then check your theme first for the correct file, and if its not present, take that file from the default theme. In many cases (and for many themes) it turns out there are many .tpl files that you may not need to touch at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own new custom OpenCart theme, use default theme folder structure. If you want to change/improve functionality of your template, you need to edit controller and models too.

But do not change core files. Always use virtual mode to modify files.

In OpenCart, there are four ways to modify its core functionality:
[vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Scripting), [OCMOD](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System), [Override Engine](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension%2Fextension%2Finfo&extension_id=8588) and [Event Handlers](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Events-%28script-notifications%29-2.2.x.x)

vQMOD / OCMOD / Override engine / Event handlers allows developer to modify files without changing any of core file. This means that if a modification is removed none of the original OpenCart files need to be restored or fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a new theme for OpenCart 1.5 used to be pretty easy - make a folder in the theme directory and copy only the files from the default theme that you want to change. And that was about it.

OpenCart 2 is now outdated, 3 should be used for new builds ...

OpenCart 3 brings new features, but creating a theme is a little more difficult.

There are instructions and a free downloadable template theme here:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-an-opencart-3-theme/